# Alphabetize by Last Name

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

how do we Alphabetize by Last Name the data that is coming from an array of objects , a thing to take note in here is that there is no separated propert like FirstName and LastName , the property is holding it as fullname (please check my example data below)

So if we alphabetize the data by last name the result would be in this order based on the data below.

One concern also if what if names are "James van der Wal" and "Mary Tyler Moore" and "Erik the Great" and "Madonna"?

What is the efficient way to handle this scenario ? Help would be much appreciated , thanks. Currently I have a solution below but willing to accept inputs. Thanks.

```
Alexa Bermodes
Bryan Christian
Alen Geizer
Philipp Hym
Mattew Merrillos
Emil Ortizano
Ivana Turnerre
Steven Weinraucherche
```

#Object - names

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "display": "Alen Geizer",
        "subDisplay": null,
        "attribute1": null,
        "attribute2": null
    },

    {
        "id": 9,
        "display": "Emil Ortizano",
        "subDisplay": null,
        "attribute1": null,
        "attribute2": null
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "display": "Philipp Hym",
        "subDisplay": null,
        "attribute1": null,
        "attribute2": null
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "display": "Bryan Christian",
        "subDisplay": null,
        "attribute1": null,
        "attribute2": null
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "display": "Ivana Turnerre",
        "subDisplay": null,
        "attribute1": null,
        "attribute2": null
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "display": "Mattew Merrillos",
        "subDisplay": null,
        "attribute1": null,
        "attribute2": null
    },
    
    {
        "id": 1,
        "display": "Alexa Bermudes",
        "subDisplay": null,
        "attribute1": null,
        "attribute2": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2299,
        "display": "Steven Weinraucherche",
        "subDisplay": null,
        "attribute1": null,
        "attribute2": null
    }
]
```

#code

#code

```
getSampleListOfNames() {
    this.isLoading = true;
    this._sample.getSampleListNames(id, '')
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => this.isLoading = false),
      ).subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          if (res.data) {
           res.data.sort((a,b) => a.display.split(" ")[1] > b.display.split(" ")[1] ? 1: -1);
            this.names = res.data;
          }
        },
        error: err => noop,
        complete: () => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Isn't the most efficient way to capture first name and last name as separate facts? What do you plan to do with names like "James van der Wal" and "Mary Tyler Moore" and "Erik the Great" and "Madonna"? Maybe the real problem is exactly that `there is no separated propert like FirstName and LastName` - why not and why can't you fix it?

Comment: It sounds to me that your problem is that you don't know what behaviour you want from your program. That's not a problem that we can help you with, as we have no way of knowing what behaviour is appropriate for your use case. You need to decide what behaviour you want before we can help with this. There may be other websites where people could talk you through different options to help you decide what behaviour you want, but that's out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Nope , the behavior I wanted is just alphabetize by last name , that's it.

Comment: It sounds strange to say, but last name is not a fully defined concept.  This is a cultural problem more than technical.

Comment: so what is your input regarding my current Solution Sir , I have added the code above.

Comment: Without additional data from the outside, your program is going to have to make a decision about what constitutes last name.  I suggest `fullname.split(' ').slice(1)`

Comment: can you post your whole answer Sir so I can upvote. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without additional external input describing what constitutes the name, a rule of thumb I've used is to define the first name as the space delimited first word, and the last name as the rest...

Taking that idea, and sorting with it...

```js
const parseName = fullname => {
  const tokens = fullname.split(' ');
  const firstname = tokens[0];
  const lastname = tokens.slice(1).join(' ');
  return {
    firstname,
    lastname
  };
};

const compareNames = (a, b) => {
  const parseA = parseName(a);
  const parseB = parseName(b);
  return parseA.lastname.localeCompare(parseB.lastname);
};

let sorted = ["Mary Tyler Moore", "Madonna", "Erik The Great"].sort(compareNames);
console.log(sorted)
```

Another edit... With objects, it's worthwhile to cache this computed parsed name so other bits of the app can use it, for example in subsequent sorts...

```js
const parseName = fullname => {
  const tokens = fullname.split(' ');
  const firstname = tokens[0];
  const lastname = tokens.slice(1).join(' ');
  return {
    firstname,
    lastname
  };
};

// this new compare compares on the cached 'parsedName' prop
const compareObjects = (a, b) => {
  return a.parsedName.lastname.localeCompare(b.parsedName.lastname);
};

// give each object a new parsedName prop
const augmentedData = getData().map(o => ({ parsedName: parseName(o.display), ...o }));

let sorted = augmentedData.sort(compareObjects);
console.log(sorted);


function getData() {
  return [{
      "id": 2,
      "display": "Alen Geizer",
      "subDisplay": null,
      "attribute1": null,
      "attribute2": null
    },

    {
      "id": 9,
      "display": "Emil Ortizano",
      "subDisplay": null,
      "attribute1": null,
      "attribute2": null
    }, {
      "id": 10,
      "display": "Philipp Hym",
      "subDisplay": null,
      "attribute1": null,
      "attribute2": null
    }, {
      "id": 11,
      "display": "Bryan Christian",
      "subDisplay": null,
      "attribute1": null,
      "attribute2": null
    }, {
      "id": 12,
      "display": "Ivana Turnerre",
      "subDisplay": null,
      "attribute1": null,
      "attribute2": null
    }, {
      "id": 13,
      "display": "Mattew Merrillos",
      "subDisplay": null,
      "attribute1": null,
      "attribute2": null
    },

    {
      "id": 1,
      "display": "Alexa Bermudes",
      "subDisplay": null,
      "attribute1": null,
      "attribute2": null
    }, {
      "id": 2299,
      "display": "Steven Weinraucherche",
      "subDisplay": null,
      "attribute1": null,
      "attribute2": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Caching the parse is a good idea for another reason: since the choice of firstname / lastname is a little arbitrary, the parsed property makes that decision explicit and centralized. With it, your colleagues using the objects (or future you) might think twice before applying their own cultural intuition to the names, causing an inconsistency.

Comment: do you have an example Sir where this code is implemented and applied to my existing one sorting which is res.data.sort((a,b) => a.display.split(" ")[1] > b.display.split(" ")[1] ? 1: -1)

Comment: @junrey, edited to demo a sort

Comment: what if on array of object Sir , on your example it is an array , mind if how do we apply that to a property from an array of objects like my sample array of objects above?

Comment: Sure, it's straight forward.  Was just about to edit to suggest you attach a sort key property to the input object (so you don't parse every time you want a sort).  Is it okay in your app to augment the objects?

Comment: Edited again using the approach I recommend.  If you don't want to -- or can't for some reason -- augment the objects.  Then skip the map and change the compare function to look more like first one I proposed.

Comment: I tried it sir , it fails when there is name like Nonina De Leon

Comment: for example is that I have names like Ali Geisere,  AlexA Bermudes, Nonina de Leon . Alexa bermudes should be first , second is Ali Geisere and third Is Nonina but right now the second one is Nonina

Comment: We've defined last name (using a cultural heuristic) as the strings after the first one.  "Bermudes" (B)  sorts before "de Leon" (D, as in "de"), which sorts before "Geisere" (G).  You can change the rule to the last string, but then "Joe Van der App" will sort before "Mary Barber".

Comment: your answer is already correct Sir, I just have one question , what sorting algorithm do we use if we wanted to sort list of company names?

Comment: In my experience, company names are sorted beginning with the first word in the name, just a basic string sort.

Comment: Thank you Sir , highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `a = [as in question]` and last name means the string following the final `" "`, you could do it like this:

```
const last = o => o.display.split(" ").pop();
a.sort((a, b) => last(a).localeCompare(last(b)))
```